# Question involving multivariable calculus.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

The temperature in  a neighbourhood of the origin is given by a function

$$T(x,y) = T_0+e^y \sin x$$

A heat fleeing particle is placed at the origin at time t = 0.
find the differential equations on the path of the particle.

I have said that the particle will travel in the direction where the temperature decreases fastest, this is given by $-\nabla T$ and

$$-\nabla T = (-e^y \cos x,-e^y \sin x)$$

so $\dot{x} = -e^y \cos x$ and  $\dot{y} = -e^y \sin x$

This is not correct apparently.

I should have

$$-\nabla T = (-e^y \cos x,e^y \sin x)$$??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I the supposed answer from a book because I would have said typo, your answer looks correct

Comment: If this is the onlz difference, then I second the opinion that it must be a typo in the text where you took this from. Your gradient is correct.